# Chaining Mongo Operators like $match, $or, and $nor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can I chain together a $or then a $nor operator when writing a mongoDb Query in node?

```
const filtersStage = [{
  $match: {
    $or: orConditions, 
    $nor: norConditions
  }
}]

const cursor = collection.aggregate([...filtersStage])
```

I keep getting: `err "$and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array"`, however if I remove one of the operators (either one), the error goes away.

How can I filter by **$or** and **$nor** in the same stage?

Comment: [your query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ALX7M82hlKT) works fine just make sure that `orConditions` and  `norConditions` are not an empty array

Comment: It's called "nesting", not "chaining"

Comment: Need to see the exact values of `orConditions` and `norConditions` when you're getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

These parameters require values to match with, so if one of the parameters is empty then it won't work, because, in the match condition something should be required to be matched.